# How to check dates and display messages - Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

first of all sorry for my bad english :)

I have firebase realtime `database` and node called: `chat_hours`

[image: chat_hours node]

- `day:0` = sunday
- `day:1` = Monday
- `...`

so, I'm getting current day from firebase:

```
// date object for chat start date
var startDate  = new Date();

// date object for chat end date
var endDate  = new Date();

// date object for date now
var now = new Date();

// current hr
var timeNow = now.getHours();

// current day to compare with firebase
var getChatDateDay = startDate.getDay(); 

// Initialize Firebase
var config = { 
  apiKey: "xxxxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxx",
  databaseURL: "xxxxx",
  projectId: "xxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxx" 
};
  firebase.initializeApp(config); 

// Get a reference to the database service
var db = firebase.database();

// Get a reference to the chat_hours node 
var chatHoursRef = db.ref('chat_hours');

chatHoursRef.orderByChild("day").equalTo(getChatDateDay).on('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function (data) {
    var value = data.val();
    
    // chat start time: (value.start) 1830
    var chatStartHourNum = value.start.toString().substr(0, 2); 
    console.log(chatStartHourNum); // Output : 18
    
    var chatStartMinuteNum = value.start.toString().substr(2, 3);
    console.log(chatStartMinuteNum); // Output : 30 
    
    // chat end time (value.end) 2230
    var chatEndHourNum = value.end.toString().substr(0, 2); 
    console.log(chatEndHourNum); // Output : 22
    
    var chatEndMinuteNum = value.end.toString().substr(2, 3);
    console.log(chatEndMinuteNum); // Output : 30
    
    // Set chat hours
    startDate.setHours(chatStartHourNum,chatStartMinuteNum,0,0);
    endDate.setHours(chatEndHourNum,chatEndMinuteNum,0,0);
     
    var chatStartHr = startDate.getHours(); 
    console.log(chatStartHr); // Outplut : 18
    
    var chatEndHr = endDate.getHours(); 
    console.log(chatEndHr); // Outplut : 22
    
    });
});
```

my question is about how to show any message:

- If chat is tonight
- If next chat is tomorrow
- if next chat is more than 24 hours
- If chat is open (not finished yet)

Comment: you need to change the implementation of your database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part where you retrieve the data I guess is clear enough for you.

Relating dates you will have first.

Define what is tonight. (Have a range of hours that you can define as tonight).

Secondly, I see that you have this request from firebase:

```
chatHoursRef.orderByChild("day").equalTo(getChatDateDay)
```

There you are limiting the answers that you get by querying DATE EQUALS TO GETCHATDAY. This will limit what you get and you will never get anything that is tomorrow.

A workaround will be:

Query all the chats (maybe some other condition, but you should not limit to the ones that has the same date as today.

- To check tonight: Get those days with the same day as today and check if the hours are in the range that you define as tonight. Eg.:

  `value.day === getChatDateDay && value.start >= tonightRangeStart && value.start < tonightRangeEnds`
- To check tomorrow: Check all those chats where day is equal to your day plus one. Eg.:

  `value.day === getChatDateDay + 1`
- To check in more than 24 hours, you could have an overlap with this one and the one that checks if the chat is tomorrow. Because a chat could be tomorrow and in more than 24 h. Example: Now 12 of Day 1 compared with Tomorrow at 13. The day will be tomorrow, but it is also more than 24 hours away. But a simple solution for this is to check that something happens tomorrow after the hour and minute of the current day. Eg.:

  `value.day === getChatDateDay + 1 && value.start > getChatDateHourAndMinute`
- To check that a chat didn't finish, you should compare your current moment with the end hour that you receive.

  `value.day === getChatDateDay && ( getChatDateHourAndMinute >= value.start && getChatDateHourAndMinute < value.end )`

The code could be done in many many ways, so I prefer not to be opinionated about it, but instead give you kind of an algorithm to solve it.

For example the variable that I called getChatDateHourAndMinute could look like:

```
var getChatDateHourAndMinute = `${startDate.getHours()}${startDate.getMinutes()}`
```

or using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: can you please show me full example code, because I'm really confuced. to take all data new query will be chatHoursRef.on('value', function(snapshot) { .....

Comment: anyway, you suggestion is right, only I'm begginer and can't focus. thanks for your answer.

Comment: I understand @GochaGochitashvili, my view on it is that: 
a) Your data model (the info that you have in firebase) is not flexible enough to can do this in an easier way and without knowing the system is difficult to do a better suggestion.
b) By using the new query that you commented, you will just get all the chats and all the hours, and then you need to do a check for each one. If you are able to publish a fiddle/codepen, usable code I could help a bit more.